# it's that possible to upload a file with encryption?

Tags: php, encryption

I try to encrypt my file, then using move_upload_file function to move my file.
if without the encrypt function i can upload my file.
but my problem is i need it encrypt my file then upload it.
anyone know the problem? plsss help....

```
$newname = dirname(__FILE__).'/upload/'.$filename;

if (!file_exists($newname)) {
    $ALGORITHM = 'AES-128-CBC';
    $IV    = '12dasdq3g5b2434b';
    $password = '123456';

    $contenuto = file_get_contents($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']);

    $contenuto = openssl_encrypt($contenuto, $ALGORITHM, $password, 0, $IV);
    $filename  = $filename . '.crypto';

    if (move_uploaded_file($contenuto,$newname)) {
        echo "It's done! The file has been saved.";
    } else {
        echo "Error: A problem occurred during file upload!";
    }
} else {
    echo "Error: File ".$_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]." already exists";
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to encrypt the file when you select it in the browser and before you transmit it to the server for PHP to process

Comment: Or are you looking for help to get this code working?

Comment: im looking for help to get this code work... but someone told me it's doesn't work...
so im asking it, this code work or not?

Comment: Sebastian Unterberg give me answer already.... thx so much!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not tested
you need to use file_put_contents for the returned string

```php
$newname = dirname(__FILE__).'/upload/'.$_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'].'.crypto';
$tempfile = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];
if (!file_exists($newname)) {
    $ALGORITHM = 'AES-128-CBC';
    $IV    = '12dasdq3g5b2434b';
    $password = '123456';
    file_put_contents($tempfile, openssl_encrypt(file_get_contents($tempfile), $ALGORITHM, $password, 0, $IV));
    if (move_uploaded_file($tempfile,$newname)) {
        echo 'It\'s done! The file has been saved.';
    } else {
        echo 'Error: A problem occurred during file upload!';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Error: File '.$_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'].' already exists';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at documentation shows that https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php openssl_encrypt returns an encrypted string, not a file. You need to save the result in a file then move it to a new destination.